# Good Perlin noise resources/implementation?

Tags: noise, perlin-noise, noise-generator

Are there any good resources out there detailing Perlin noise generation? I understand that most languages have noise generating libraries available, but I'm interested in creating my own for fun/experience. I've already looked at [this](http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_perlin.htm), which seems pretty popular, but it only gives an in-depth explanation of one dimensional noise. Google searches have been relatively unhelpful so far, as most of them focus on applications instead of how to create a generator.

Books and/or websites are welcome, even if their focus is not the generation itself so long as it gives a thorough explanation of an implementation, or at least the concepts involved so I can "discover" my own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well this link [here](http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_perlin.htm) has some decent information. There is also [Ken Perlin's site](http://www.noisemachine.com/talk1/).
A quick search on [Google](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=perlin+noise+generation&aq=f&aqi=g2&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) provides a lot of generators and implementations in different languages.

[Here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/~imcgarve/perlin_noise/) is one generator I know of that has source available (scroll down to the bottom of the page).

You may also want to search around http://www.gamedev.net as there are a lot of forum posts etc. on perlin noise generation.

Comment: The first link you posted I've already commented on, though I am glad you reminded me of Ken Perlin's site. However, I would like to see some source code or examples, since he only describes 2D noise in a paragraph or two. And as I said before, Google gives plenty of hits on generators and libraries I could use, but is pretty lacking on implementations.

Comment: oh sorry, I have no idea how I misred your post, I added another link to the above

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one that I wrote and released on Github.  It's a 4-dimensional Perlin generator written in Objective-C.  http://czgarrett.com/code/2011/05/18/perlin-noise-generator-for-ios.html